# I use ion-radio , but the check mark don't appear when click on one item

Tags: ionic-framework

I have two radio button let's say A and B , when I check A the checkmark appears, then if I check B it doesn't appear first time clicked, but if I re-click again it appear. What's the problem :

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-radio ng-model="vm.recoverBy" ng-value="'GetID'">
     A
    </ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="vm.recoverBy" ng-value="'GetPass'">
     B
    </ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

the answer is : add name="giveItAName" to the two ion-radio item:

```
  <ion-radio ng-model="vm.recoverBy" 
               ng-value="'GetID'"
               name="recover">
     A
    </ion-radio>
    <ion-radio ng-model="vm.recoverBy" 
               ng-value="'GetPass'"
               name="recover">
     B
    </ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```